# Moving balls using vectors

Tags: animation, math, vector

I want to move some balls in specific direction. This direction is determined by a "pointer" - which is a simple line with `x1,y1 and x2,y2` coordinates.

[image]

From this line I get its vector. `v = (x2-x1, y2-y1)`. This vector is then used to move the balls.

```
ball.x += v.x;
ball.y += v.y;
```

This works fine as long as I don't want to slow the balls down. To slow them down I divided the vector by 5, which should result in smaller vector with the same direction.

```
v = (x2-x1)/5,(y2-y1)/5;
```

This solution slows the balls down, however it also changes their direction. So it look something like this :[image]

What should I do in order to slow the balls down without this direction change ?

Comment: Are vector components integers?

Comment: No, they are floats. Is that a problem ?

Comment: No, described behaviour might be sometimes explained with integer division issues (integer 3/5 = 0). Have you checked `v` components values after division? Seems it is worth to show real code pieces.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show actual data. From the question and the two images it looks like v.x and v.y are modified in different ways instead of staying proportional. Please show the whole code and the values of ball.x, ball.y, v.x and v.y during the execution.

Comment: You were right. It was because the vector had float components, however the coordinates of ball were integers.